# Tweepy 4.0: "'Listener' object has no attribute 'running'" error?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to convert a basic streaming-Twitter bot to Tweepy 4.0 alpha, in order to take advantage of some of the newer features. However, I can't even get it started, using the docs that describe the new streaming protocol.

I've reduced my program to a test case, but running it still gives the error `AttributeError: 'MyStreamListener' object has no attribute 'running'`. Can someone point out where my problem is? There don't seem to be any other questions about this particular error, and I was trying to follow the docs closely. I had to make some guesses because of the lack of examples--for instance, connecting to the stream requires a different set of parameters than connecting to the regular api, hence the two `get_auth` calls--but for the moment I'm more interested in just getting it to work than getting things to be super clean.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import tweepy
import json
import configparser
import os


def _read_config():
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    config_file = os.path.join(script_dir, '../bot-config.ini')
    config.read(config_file)
    return config


def _get_api_auth(config):
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(
        config['auth']['consumer_key'], config['auth']['consumer_secret'])
    auth.set_access_token(config['auth']['token'],
                          config['auth']['token_secret'])
    return auth


def _get_stream_auth(config):
    return (config['auth']['consumer_key'], config['auth']['consumer_secret'],
            config['auth']['token'], config['auth']['token_secret'])


class MyStreamListener(tweepy.Stream):

    def __init__(self, stream_auth, api):
        super(tweepy.Stream, self).__init__()
        self._api = api
        self._tweet_count = 0

    def on_data(self, data):
        tweet = json.loads(data)

        if 'text' not in tweet:
            return

        self._tweet_count += 1

        if tweet['truncated']:
            text = tweet['extended_tweet']['full_text']
        else:
            text = tweet['text']

        if 'Rumplestiltskin' in text:
            try:
                self._api.retweet(tweet['id'])
                print('Tweeted id %d!', tweet['id'])
            except tweepy.TweepError as err:
                print('Unable to tweet %d:', tweet['id'])
                print(err.reason)

        if (self._tweet_count % 10000) == 0:
            print('Processed %s tweets', self._tweet_count)


def run():

    config = _read_config()

    api_auth = _get_api_auth(config)
    api = tweepy.API(api_auth)
    stream_auth = _get_stream_auth(config)

    twitterStream = MyStreamListener(stream_auth, api)
    twitterStream.sample()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Answer (score 2):

Bah, this was basically just a simple Python error, as pointed out by someone in the Discord server. I'll leave it here in case anyone else makes the same mistake; basically I needed to call it with all the auth stuff individually, so the calling line should be:

```
 twitterStream = MyStreamListener(config['auth']['consumer_key'],
                                       config['auth']['consumer_secret'],
                                       config['auth']['token'],
                                       config['auth']['token_secret'],
                                       api)
```

I also got the `super` syntax wrong; it should be:

```
def __init__(self, cons_key, cons_secret, token, token_sec, api):
    super().__init__(cons_key, cons_secret, token, token_sec)
```

That's it.